# SQLite quirky database table lock

Tags: java, sqlite

I am using **sqlite** as the database of an application.It works fine on everything but when i am going to delete a table from the database then it throws this error using [https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc]:

**Error**

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_LOCKED]  A table in the database is locked (database table is locked)
```

I am using **no-auto-commit-mode** so before deleting the table i had already committed.Why this is happening?

A possible solution is to close the connection and re-open it but this can't be done because other actions are taking place simultanesouly.

**

### Solution is:------------------------

**

I was counting the rows of a table into a thread using:

```
connection1.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIBRARIES;").getInt(1);
```

but this returns a result set which was never closed so the database table was forever locked!!

Comment: Are you using shared-cache mode?

Comment: @CL. I am using a connection which is on autoCommit(false) and i commit every time.How shared-cache is used?It has do with multiple thread?Thanks for help man.

Comment: Shared-cache mode (which you should *not* use) would be a possible source of the error.

Comment: @CL. i am using multiple threads on my app.Is shared mode <on> with this?Reading this to use shared-memory i should have more than one connections but i use only 1.Am i wrong?

Comment: No, it would have to be enabled explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).
It is not possible for multiple programs/threads to access the database at the same time when one is writing.

You should set a timeout to allow your thread to wait for others to finish.

Comment: In 15 minutes solved 2 months problem,thanks!.I had one thread which is executing this command for getting total rows of the table'Libraries' <<connection1.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIBRARIES;").getInt(1)>> and is locking for some reason  every table why this might happen?

Comment: Every transaction locks the entire database.

Comment: Fff i found the ResultSet of this command was never closed.OMG thanks man.